# Apache HttpClient for Java Specific GET instead of CONNECT

Tags: java, httpclient

Is there a way to specify the connection method when using a proxy?
I'm using the below code which sends an HTTP CONNECT. That is not supported by my load balancer. A GET request would terminate the TLS connection between the proxy and the website. The CONNECT method creates a TLS connection end to end between the end user and website. Essentially I need to inspect the traffic at the proxy.

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);

    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    clientBuilder
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .setProxy(proxy)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config);
```

Below is what the connection looks like:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
CONNECT xyz.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: xyz.com\r\n
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/19.0.1)\r\n
\r\n
```

Comment: The easiest answer is use http: instead of https:.  Of course, if you don't control the server this is not an option.  I've posted some notes on a spoofing proxy (unfortunately spoofing proxy is not the right keyword AFAIK).

Comment: In python, i was able to modify the url. IE instead of setting the proxy, I just changed where base url and sent the GET to the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

For HTTPS communications through a proxy, the client will use a CONNECT request to create a connection through the proxy to the remote trusted site.

With HTTPS, the client will only communicate with a server that it trusts.  The trust usually requires that the server presents an X.509 certificate that is signed by a trusted authority (not self-signed), not expired, and has a subject that matches the site the client is trying to reach.

When communicating with a proxy, the proxy is typically unable to match that criteria.  However, there are proxies that can match the above criteria by generating a new cert on the fly that has a matching subject to that expected by the client.

In that case, once the client has established a TLS connection with the proxy, the proxy can then decrypt the payload of the HTTPS traffic.

For the proxy to create a certificate trusted by the client, it must be signed by a CA (certificate authority) that is trusted by the client.   Now, by default, the client will not trust the cert since it will not recognize the CA.  However, you may modify the client by placing a cert for the CA on the client.  Once the client trusts the CA, it will trust all of the certs generated by the proxy.

That being said, here's configuration for an HTTPS proxy (written by Cisco) that provides instructions for just that:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/unified-communications/jabber/212044-Configure-Charles-Proxy-to-Capture-HTTPS.html

The configuration action you'll need for Apache (if Apache supports this) will be similar - you'll need to get a cert from the Apache proxy to install on your client.

I'm currently searching the web for similar proxies.  I'm essentially looking for a key word that describes this technique of enabling your HTTPS proxy to do man-in-the-middle attacks with a dynamically generated cert matching the request.  If I find the terms, I'll update the post.

EDIT:  Update for squid

I found an article about configuring squid for inspecting HTTPS traffic:  https://scubarda.com/2020/03/23/configure-squid-proxy-for-ssl-tls-inspection-https-interception/

In the article, the author indicates that you would have to install the X.509 Cyber Saiyan certificate in your browser (client's) certificate/authorities section (but this is just for this specific configuration).

Some good keywords to search for now are HTTPS inspection...

Answer (score 0):

If this is a temporary debug solution, you can use one of the Man In The Middle (MITM) proxies that are designed just for this:

- [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/proxy)
- [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)
- [Zap](https://www.zaproxy.org/)

Once installed somewhere, you'll just need to import the proxy CA cert into the server making the connections (each of the above proxies has a how-to guide for this), and set the proxy address to the MITM.